# How can i stop autopct changing my specified sizes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've tried a few different ways of fixing this code, however, i think it's something to do with this bit '(p/100)' - i just need (below the percentage) a reading of the exact amount of miles that i'm pasing to 'sizes'

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data to plot
labels = 'Winter Period', 'Summer Period'
sizes = 227000447618.80783, 306368375052.34174
colors = ['lightskyblue', 'gold']

# Plot
plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels, colors=colors,
autopct=lambda p: '{:.2f}% \n ({:.5f} \n Miles)'.format(p,(p/100)*sum(sizes)), 
        textprops={'fontsize': 9}, shadow=True, startangle=140)

plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[Results of running this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shYw4.png)

Comment: I think it changed because of the floating point operation. Do you must put the miles info on the autopct? If not, I would suggest to put it into the labels instead

Comment: @Yosua I think i may have to do that for the time being - however, i do believe you're correct with it being something to do with the floating point number.